# Parental Control Software

Tags: php, python, proxy

I have been developing a parental control software program for my company, but have run into a problem. The software uses policy listings stored in a MySQL DB to determine whether to block a website or not. It uses a local proxy. Each time a website is visited, the proxy sends that site to the server, then the server determines if the site should be blocked or not based on the settings for the user. The software is done, but there is one major problem. It takes too long for the address to be sent to the server, and the server's response to get back to the proxy. Browsing speed is slowed down a lot when using the software. Is there a better way to do this?

The proxy is written in Python and everything on the server end is done in PHP.

Comment: what part of it is taking long? the queries themselves? network time too high? url parsing?

Comment: @Matt The queries to the DB run smoothly. It seems to be the passing of the URLs to the server from the client that take too long. I have used urllib for POST and GET (not that there is much difference between the two) and also httplib for POST and GET. Neither of them have worked fast enough.

Comment: Do you send the URL on a site by site basis or URL by URL? If it's site by site, it shouldn't affect the speed because you could cache the response on your end.

Comment: The records in the DB are matched with the user's username, which is also sent via the POST/or GET. @JohnP, they are sent URL by URL. Is this where I made the mistake?

Comment: @Zachary since you're vetting every URL that's an added step so it might affect browsing speed. You'll need to find out whether the slowness is because of processing on your part or whether it's because the user has to wait for your response. Would it be possible to send a list of blacklisted/whitelisted URLs for the current site on initial load? If it is, you could cache it on the client side and check that before pinging your server. That would take out the round trip time (_if_ that's the reason that makes browsing slow that is)

Comment: @JohnP, the slowness is due to the time it takes for the server's response to get back to the client. So, I would first have the proxy check the cache, then if the URL isn't there, I ask the server. I then cache that response so in the immediate future, the process goes along much faster? How often should the cache be updated?

Comment: Replace the PHP code with python, you will find a speed up if its written properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you caching the server's responses locally on the client?  If not, you should - it ought to speed things up considerably.

And if you're asking your server about each URL, you should only ask about the domain name, so that the number of requests per site goes down from lots to only one.  (Unless there are domains for which you only want to ban a part of it, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: So, I cache the responses for each domain visited, thus speeding up the browsing speed and limiting URLs sent to the server. How should the responses be cached on the client side?

Comment: I would just add them to a `dict`.  Storing them on disk seems like overkill, and is vulnerable to tampering.  And the data won't get very big, unless someone visits a million separate domains.  (You could always randomly cull half the entries when it gets to some threshold.)

Comment: @RichieHindle, I see... very good idea. I'll give it a try and get back.

Comment: @RichieHindle, the user has an administrative console, which is online, that allows themto make policy changes etc. How would I update the dict every 10 mins?

Comment: The simplest answer is to just empty the dictionary every ten minutes - all that would happen is that for each domain visited after that, there'd be one round trip to the server.  But I wonder whether you're asking the wrong question - do you mean "how do I transmit policy changes from the server to the PC?"  If so, one easy way is to ask the server every 30 seconds or so whether the cache needs flushing.  Do that as a separate connection, independent of what the user is doing via the proxy.

Comment: I think you are right! I need to transmit the policy from the server to the client. Checking every 30 seconds would be great because the cache would always be up to date. But how would I do this within one script, using different connections? Would I use threading somehow?

Comment: @Zachary: Yes, or asynchronous networking (asyncore, Twisted, etc.)

Comment: Ok, the proxy is written using Twisted, so would using Twisted provide an easier alternative to asyncore?

Comment: If you're already using Twisted, that's perfect - Twisted makes this sort of thing easy.

Comment: I've never done this myself. But I'm sure a search for Twisted HTTP Client will find some useful examples.